# Reduce BMP file size without losing quality

Tags: image-format, file-size

The input file format is BMP. The required output format is BMP. I do not want a reduction of size or quality, but I want to reduce the file size. How is it possible?

Comment: Out of curiosity: What purpose requires you to use BMP?

Comment: What kind of color depths are we talking here?

Comment: It is a valid question. 24 bit BMP on Windows, as far as I know, **do NOT** accept compression.

Comment: Some aplications needs a bmp file as source images before compiling them. For example one client needed them for a touch screen for a control pannel on an odonthological laser. This BMP files are compressed when compiled.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use file compression tools - like zipping or adding to rar.
2. Reduce 24 bits to lower. But that'd be lossy.

So, you don't really have a way afaik.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, [BMP supports some compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_bitmap#Compression), though I do not know whether any programs actually support it. But then I am not using BMP anyway.

Comment: Acoording to that quote the one that accepts compression on 24 bits is the OS2 operating sistem, that was from IBM long ago extint.